# Creating and firing touch events on a touch enabled browser?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to fire touch events in my JavaScript to simulate user interactions for the purpose of testing features. I have tried the following snippet:

```
try {
    var targetElement = document.elementFromPoint(55, 155);
    console.log(targetElement);
    var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
    evt.initTouchEvent('touchstart', true, true);
    
    evt.view = window;
    evt.altKey = false;
    evt.ctrlKey = false;
    evt.shiftKey = false;
    evt.metaKey = false;
    
    targetElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
} catch (except){
    alert(except);
}
```

The above code throws the exception:

> TypeError: Result of expression 'evt.initTouchEvent[undefined]' is not a function.

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [w3c touch spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webevents/raw-file/tip/touchevents.html), `TouchEvent` is a subclass of UIEvent. Try creating it like:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
```

Comment: Tried and still the same exception. The UIEvent object _is created_ whether I use the singular or the plural.

Comment: I don't have a device to test it right now. Will test and update tomorrow.

Comment: @Ashu AFAIK the Android emulator has a mobile WebKit in it.

Answer (score 5):

change:

```
evt.initTouchEvent('touchstart', true, true);
```

to:

```
evt.initUIEvent('touchstart', true, true);
```

worked for me with nightly chrome build