# Simulate a click on 'a' element using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, click, simulate

I am trying to simulate a click on on an element.
HTML for the same is as follows

```
<a id="gift-close" href="javascript:void(0)" class="cart-mask-close p-abs" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','voucher_new','cart',$(this).attr('rel')+'-mask_x_button-inaction']);" rel="coupon">&nbsp;</a>
```

How can i simulate a click on it. I have tried

`document.getElementById("gift-close").click();`

But its not doing anything

Comment: Where are you doing `document.getElementById("gift-close").click();` from? It will work if you do it from an onload handler (or otherwise ensure the `<a>` element exists): http://jsfiddle.net/LKNYg/

Comment: If you are really using jQuery, this is one of the most basic things you learn first. Please check out [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/) to learn more.

Comment: I want to make the inline onclick handler execute

Comment: Please, just please do not write `href="javascript:void(0)"`. It has critical SEO issues.

Comment: Please note that user-click and triggered programmed click work differently.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127908/difference-between-click-and-actually-clicking-a-button-javascript-jquery/59028088#59028088

Answer (score 148):

Using jQuery: `$('#gift-close').trigger('click');`

Using JavaScript: `document.getElementById('gift-close').click();`

Comment: `document.getElementById('gift-close').onClick();` doesn't work in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari. However, changing `onClick()` to `click()` does work.

Comment: Didn't the asker explicity say that this *doesn't* work? I don't understand the upvotes.

Comment: @HugoZink because it **does** work..? Did you try anything before downvoting/commenting?

Comment: @AndréDion I did, and it does not seem to work in Firefox. Probably due to security concerns.

Answer (score 21):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#gift-close').click();
```

Comment: Why would that work when `document.getElementById("gift-close").click();` didn't?

Comment: Because document.getElementById("gift-close") is not a jQuery object but a DOM object. You could try this too: $(document.getElementById("gift-close")).click();

Comment: @techfoobar and Alex, DOM elements have a `.click()` method. http://jsfiddle.net/LKNYg/

Comment: @nnnnnn - Wow! Totally new info for me.. Never knew that.. Tks :-)

Comment: Oh, yes. You're right. Then the problem is that he should execute click code after page loading, i.e. in onReady event ;)

Comment: @roasted - It did fire the inline `onclick` for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/LKNYg/2/ (but from past experience I believe it wouldn't cause actual navigation if it was a "proper" anchor with an `href` containing a URL).

Comment: @nnnnnn you are right! Just the native behaviour of anchor tag is not fired, my bad!

Comment: I want to make the inline onclick handler execute

Comment: Shouldn't Be used any more because of Jquery 3.6.0 it's outdated.

Answer (score 17):

Try to use `document.createEvent` described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent

The code for function that simulates click should look something like this:

```
function simulateClick() {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var a = document.getElementById("gift-close"); 
  a.dispatchEvent(evt);      
}
```

Comment: Also look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951468/what-is-a-good-example-of-using-event-constructors-in-js this describes newer approach to creating custom events.

Comment: Wow awesom! I just tried your solution to upvote your answer and it really works:)
If anyone want to try? Do this in console....

var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
var a = $('div#answer-17569610 a.vote-up-off').get(0);
a.dispatchEvent(evt);

Comment: Change "document.createEvent" to "new CustomEvent" to conform to new standards.
This is the better solution, as it realy simulates a click, which sometimes is not the same as simply firing the onClick event. Especially if the element is doing 2 things, like opening a link (in a new window?) and handling the Click event (to do something on the same page).
Thanks Ihor.

Answer (score 10):

**Code snippet underneath!**

Please take a look at these documentations and examples at **MDN**, and you will find your answer. This is the propper way to do it I would say.

[Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events)

[Dispatch Event (example)](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html)

Taken from the 'Dispatch Event (example)'-HTML-link (simulate click):

```
function simulateClick() {

  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");

  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

  var cb = document.getElementById("checkbox"); 
  var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(evt);

  if(canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}
```

> **This is how I would do it (2017 ..) :**
>
> Simply using [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent).
>
> ```
> function simulateClick() {
>
>     var evt = new MouseEvent("click");
>
>     var cb = document.getElementById("checkbox");
>     var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
>
>     if (canceled) {
>         // A handler called preventDefault
>         console.log("canceled");
>     } else {
>         // None of the handlers called preventDefault
>         console.log("not canceled");
>     }
> }
> ```

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = evt => {
    
    simulateClick()
}

function simulateClick() {

    var evt = new MouseEvent("click");

    var cb = document.getElementById("checkbox");
    var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(evt);

    if (canceled) {
        // A handler called preventDefault
        console.log("canceled");
    } else {
        // None of the handlers called preventDefault
        console.log("not canceled");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<br>
<br>
<button id="button">Check it out, or not</button>
```

Answer (score 9):

The code you've already tried:

```
document.getElementById("gift-close").click();
```

...should work as long as the element actually exists in the DOM at the time you run it. Some possible ways to ensure that include:

1. Run your code from an `onload` handler for the window. http://jsfiddle.net/LKNYg/
2. Run your code from a document ready handler if you're using jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/LKNYg/1/
3. Put the code in a script block that is *after* the element in the source html.

So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("gift-close").click();
    // OR
    $("#gift-close")[0].click();
});
```

Comment: I want to make the inline onclick handler execute

Comment: Right. And that happens in both of the jsfiddle demos I provided.

Comment: The trick I found (compared to the "best" answer) was to use the [0]. That caused the script to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to click:

```
$("#gift-close").click();
```

Comment: Why would that work when `document.getElementById("gift-close").click();` didn't?

Comment: You have to run your code  from `onload` handler for javascript, or  `$(document).ready(function(){//write code here})` for JQuery

Answer (score -3):

Here, try this one:

```
$('#gift-close').on('click', function () {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','voucher_new','cart',$(this).attr('rel')+'-mask_x_button-inaction']);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Try adding a function inside the `click()` method.

```
$('#gift-close').click(function(){
  //do something here
});
```

It worked for me with a function assigned inside the click() method rather than keeping it empty.

Comment: this is a click event listener, not a click event trigger