# Click an 'a' element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have gone through [Simulate a click on 'a' element using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569012/simulate-a-click-on-a-element-using-javascript-jquery) but it didn't help.

The code I am running against is

```
<a target="gsft_main" id="9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011" data-cancelable="true" class="menu" href="discovery_status_list.do?sysparm_userpref_module=9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011">Status</a>
```

I have executed below code

```
document.getElementById('9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011').click()
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried

```
$('#9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011').trigger('click')
```

with no success. If I run

```
document.getElementById('9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011')
```

it returns null.

Comment: if you're getting null, then the element doesn't exist when you're executing that code. Please check that at first.

Comment: what is data-cancelable="true" doing?

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: Chances are you are running the code before the element in your page without using onload. Please verify

Comment: Click action is working. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oak7ncsv/

Comment: I don't think starting an Id with a number is valid - try using a letter to start the Id instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1370442

Comment: @bUKaneer Only for HTML4

Comment: Did you try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click ?

Comment: Most likely that anchor tag's id is created dynamically. So when you try to target it by ID, it will return null since that ID is changed each time. Did you inspect your page that the anchor tag actually have the same ID??

Comment: I am trying to automate clicking on this 'a' tag. I am trying this from console which we get by inspecting element in chrome. id is not dynamically created, I verified that couple of times. This website hasn't been created by me, and it works pretty well when I am manually clicking on that link. I did 'document.getElementById('9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011').href' but it again returned null.

Comment: @zvona- I am unsure of this as I haven't created this site.

Comment: @HorstGutmann- Sorry if this doesn't relate to JSON. My lack of scripting XP to blame :( ... I was trying to use either to accomplish clicking...

Comment: @Huangism- I checked this many times, it is static...

Comment: @Aravind- It's working indeed. I did some changes and that too worked. So why is console on google chrome not getting this, confused!

Answer (score 0):

To trigger an 'a' element directly doesn't work in this case. If you wrap your text in a span and trigger a click event on the span it should work.

```
<a id="test" href="http://stackoverflow.com"><span>Status</span></a>
```

and with jquery:

```
$('#test span').trigger('click');
```

if you get a null on document.getElementById('9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011') you probably made a typo...

Comment: Can't span it as I have not created this website. I am trying to automate click on that link after every, say 5 seconds or so. I am trying this from console provided by chrome. I also tried 'document.getElementById('9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011').href' but this too returns null. But it works well when I click on that link manually. Since I have less XP in scripting, I am unsure of many things. But since I know coding, I am able to get my head around a few :)

Comment: Try: $('#9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011')[0].click(); That should also work.

Comment: I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null' If I run the command normally, it is returning 'null' all the time. I think may be this is the problem. When I simply execute '$('#9ddfe6c10a0a0b7e0062ccf1e8afc011')', it gives 'null'

Comment: What happens when you try $('.menu'); ?