# Forcing touch event in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have an issue with `CSS` on my mobile device with `hybrid app`..so after some changes, only after clicking anywhere on the screen all getting fixed-refreshing. I wonder is any way I can force touch event on randomly position on screen with `JavaScript`?

The reason I'm asking this, because I have problem that already was asked about `bxSlider` : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873597/pager-item-coloring-duplication-bxslider

I have noticed that touching or clicking any place on screen solves the problem - like refreshing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713393/creating-and-firing-touch-events-on-a-touch-enabled-browser

Comment: Can you described you problem with more details. Maybe we can fix the main reason.

Comment: @Gajotres I added the reason- describes the problem, to the question...

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery trigger: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$('.someObject').trigger('touchstart');
```

Comment: Checked it...while debugging with `Chrome` and testing for `touch-click` event, this code didn't did anything.